# Display image on whole QGraphicsScene in Qt

Tags: qt

I want the graphics scene to show image that covers it whole. I create the scene with same size as an image, but get this result:

[image]

Could you please suggest what is wrong with the code? Thanks

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QGraphicsPixmapItem * image = new QGraphicsPixmapItem(QPixmap("C:\\data\\99.png"));
    int imageWidth = image->pixmap().width();
    int imageHeight = image->pixmap().height();
    image->setOffset(- imageWidth / 2, -imageHeight / 2);
    image->setPos(0, 0);

    QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene();
    scene->setSceneRect(-imageWidth / 2, -imageHeight / 2, imageWidth, imageHeight);
    QGraphicsView * gv = new QGraphicsView();
    ui->gridLayout->addWidget(gv);
    gv->setScene(scene);

    qInfo()<<"width image " <<imageWidth; // 640
    qInfo()<<"height image " <<imageHeight; // 400
    qInfo()<<"width scene " <<scene->width(); // 640
    qInfo()<<"height scene " <<scene->width(); // 400
    gv->scene()->addItem(image);
    gv->show();

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scene has the same size of the image, but the View doesn't, the view can be freely scalled.

what you need is to make the View to understand that the scene should be 100% of the view.

for this, create a class that inherit from QGraphivsView and override the resizeEvent,  implement the following:

```
void GraphicsView::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event)
{
    QGraphicsView::resizeEvent(event);
    fitInView(sceneRect(), Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio);
    fixBackgroundPos();
}
```

this will always zoom the QGraphivsView to fit the whole scene.